# VideoCapture Error: vidcap.Error: Cannot set capture resolution

Tags: python

```
from VideoCapture import Device

cam = Device()
cam.setResolution(320, 240)
cam.saveSnapshot('demo.jpg')
```

I use VideoCapture in Windows Python2.7 .I do not know what`s wrong.How do I solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ideaProject/python_workspace/webcap/webcap/test/vc.py", line 8, in <module>
    cam.setResolution(320, 240)
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\VideoCapture.py", line 90, in setResolution
    self.dev.setresolution(width, height)
vidcap.Error: Cannot set capture resolution.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read the VideoCapture.py with a deep look,I find a solution :

```
from VideoCapture import Device

cam = Device()
cam.getImage(timestamp=0).resize((320, 240)).save('demo.jpg', quality=80)
```

I can get the right size of the photo.Perhaps I use wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, your solution looks more like a workaround. I guess you didn't change your camera's resolution, what your code did is to use your camera to capture an original picture and by using resize() function to change the captured picture's size then. That means, what you are doing looks like you capture a picture first(which doesn't have your desired resolution), then you go to edit that captured picture. If I'm wrong, I appreciate you can point that out cause I'm faced with this problem, too.

Comment: Yes,I wanted to capture an original picture, resize and save it.